# reply with a different account - multiple email accounts

Tags: email, 4.2-jelly-bean, exchange, stock-email-app

I have an Exchange account, e.g. `hub@domain.com`, that I forward all my emails to from all my other accounts. But I need to reply to these messages using different accounts, e.g. reply to a work email with `me@work.com` - how could I do that in Android?

#### Default Email App in 4.2.2

Hitting reply on an email in my hub account does not let me change the account to send the reply with (e.g. work account). I can go to my work account and compose a new email there and copy paste the original email and subject and receivers manually, but that is cumbersome.

#### TouchDown

Only supports Exchange accounts, but no IMAP, which I need to set up my other accounts.

#### Solution?

Is it doable

- With the native app would be best solution (is there anywhere to submit feature requests for Email app?)
- With any other email app that I have not tried?

Comment: FYI, the Gmail app does let you reply from a different account, even those that aren't a Gmail address. If you authorize Gmail to spoof it's FROM adress to look like it's coming from your work email address.

Comment: @Chrisii & geffchang thanks for the answers, they solve the core of the issue. unfortunately, im dependent on Exchange 2010 as well, so if anyone knows of any app having the "from" choice feature as well as supporting ActiveSync that would be awesome!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[K-9 Mail](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.fsck.k9) allows to choose the "from" mail address when composing a message (or replying to a received message). Click the "from" address field and a pop-up menu will appear which allows you to choose the appropriate account.

K-9 supports pop/imap/exchange(via webdav) accounts.

Pictures for illustration

compose window:

[image: compose window picture]

account chooser:

[image: send as]

Comment: Probably should make those pictures smaller, imgur lets you do it.

Comment: @Peanut I am not quite sure how to accomplish this. I simply added the pictures via the editor. Stack-Exchange automatically uploads them to imgur. (Of course I could resize the pictures and upload them manually ..)

Comment: Ah sorry, I thought you'd uploaded them to imgur yourself. I'll just resize them for you.

Comment: @Peanut thanks, sorry for all the inconvenience I caused

Comment: @Peanut,Chrissi: if you add the letter "s", "m", or "l" to the end of the URL of an imageur images, you'll get a resized version. See: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25051/resizing-an-image-in-a-post

Comment: @LieRyan, brilliant: thanks for the awesome tip

Comment: Does this still work?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Kaiten Mail, an advanced version of K-9 Mail. It supports multiple IMAP, POP3, Exchange 2003/2007 (via WebDAV); but not Exchange ActiveSync.

When you reply to a message, you can change the sender. If you click on the header (email address), a "Send as" dialog will popup.

Comment: im field-testing Kaiten now, and the "send as" worked; not sure how ill solve the activesync issue though..

Answer (score 0):

I was going to type only Gmail, but answer has to be at least 30 chars long lol. I have all my emails connected to my gmail account, the same that my android phone use. I am sending emails from like 7 email addresses 4 of them are gmail, 2 other are different email provider, the last one is my own server. You can manage all emails on 1 account and selecting email as sender is as easy as picking the from email in a select box. Only problem I have that sometimes in conversation the mobile app doesnt use the from email I used through this particular conversation and I accidantely send it from my personal email, which I dont give to anyone. I actually found this quesrion when I was searching the solution for this problem.